# Unable to click on Facebook "setting" link through selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

My Java

```
package com.palash.healthcare;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login {
@Test
@Parameters({"URL","USERNAME","PASSWORD"})
public static void logindata(String url,String Username,String Password)
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(Username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(Password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_v")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_54nh'][text()='Settings']")).click();
    List<WebElement> All_List = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='_54nf']"));
    for(WebElement li:All_List)
    {
        System.out.println(li.getText());
        if(li.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Settings"));
        li.click();
    }


}

}
```

I am writing the facebook Setting link script in selenium webdriver with java but I am unable to click on the Setting link also i have tried the above code.Can Anybody Help? and for the html about the script you can see the facebook Setting link  right above the "logout" button.

Comment: Please share html code

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what's going on with that list. I  don't think you'll need that but correct me if I'm wrong.

The web app I do work for is really wonky and sometimes you have to do some weird stuff. Try something like:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement settings = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_54nh'][text()='Settings']"));
actions.moveToElement(settings).build().perform();
settings.click();
```

This  kinda breaks the `.click()` down into smaller steps.

Took me a long while to get `.click()` commands down. They behave differently on different web applications.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: we don't need Action class here,but your Xpath is correct.Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just navigating to the settings page after you log in? It's https://www.facebook.com/settings.

Comment: Yes this one is the another option but I have to click the settings link.Also you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_54nh'][text()='Settings']")).click();
```

Got the Answer Just Need to reconstruct the Xpath.

Comment: You don't want to use Thread.sleep(), it's not a good practice because what if 3s is not long enough or what if the page is ready in 100ms and you still have to wait 3s? Instead use WebDriverWait and wait until the 2nd element is clickable then click it.